# Linux Mint power consumption / CPU

Tags: linux, battery, linux-mint

I installed Linux Mint 12(lisa) on my dell lx502 i.e. XPS 15 with an i7-670QM cpu and the nvidia 550M with optimus.

However I am concerned about the power consumption. 
About 21% battery ~= 36 minutes, while this is double in Windows 7 (with aero on). 
I've installed Jupiter, but does not seem to help a lot. 
My screen brightness is set to minimum.

My question is how I can make it be a little more power efficient and achieve similar battery performance like windows - 5.5Hrs on a 9 cell battery.

```
ren@zeus ~ $ uname -a
Linux zeus 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Li
```

Comment: I assume this problem is tied to the optimus chip, are you running intel or nvidia drivers?

Comment: no, I haven't installed the nvidia drivers. 
I guess it has picked up some default drivers like vesa.. not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and run `powertop` which advises on what kernel parameters to change. It will merely run through guidelines of [Lesswatts](http://lesswatts.org). Also try OpenSUSE live CD – if it has better results, as it has radically different PM mechanism.

Comment: I'll give powertop a go, I've installed the nvidia drivers as well, I think it might help will keep you posted.

Comment: Also try ubuntu with LXDE (lubuntu) - it is designed for underpowered computers, and will draw less power on your s (mine is like 5 years old and it is (OpenSUSE 64bit) KDE - 30W -> LXDE - 22W using idle desktop

Comment: well my computer is not underpowered :(

Comment: I don't like LXDE :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest bios update.  I know I had an issue with Mint on my Acer laptop where I could not see the battery level.  Looking on forums I could not figure it out.  Finally I decide to update the BIOS and low and behold I was able to see the battery percentage.  Getting drivers from the DELL website that are native linux may also help.  Good luck!